# Отображать новости только на главной странице, DataLife Engine

Tags: dle

Мне надо сделать так, чтоб когда я создал файл `http://сайт.ру/index.php/services.tpl`, в нем были не новости (`{info}{content}`), а то, что хранится в файле `services.tpl`. То есть мне надо, чтобы новости были только на главной странице.

Вставлял `[aviable=main]{info}{content}[/aviable]` в `main.tpl`, но в `services.tpl` все равно продолжают выводиться новости.

Путь к файлу `services.tpl` отображается  в ftp-клиенте как `/public_html/templates/Default/services.tpl`.
Путь к файлу через сайт: `http://сайт.ру/index.php/services.tpl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> http://сайт.ру/index.php/services.tpl

Ну так ссылка то и не правильная. Если вам нужен новый раздел, то ссылка должна быть http://site.ru/?do=services

А в коде оставить ваше aviable=main, а после дописать

```
[aviable=services]{include file="services.tpl"}[/aviable]
```

---

UPD.

Кстати нужно писать вот так:

```
[not-aviable=services]{content}[/not-aviable]
```

а не как вы укказали

Comment: А как сделать ?do=services

Comment: Так я ж и говорю. В коде пропишите то, что я вам выше указал и контент этого шаблона будет доступен по ссылке ?do=services

Comment: Дак мне надо, чтоб на главной странице были новости, а на services было то что в папке services.tpl

Comment: Все, я понял)) Спасибо вам!

Comment: Пожалуйста :) Если помог, отметьте вопрос правильным